# How can i use custom dbcontext (Audit Log) with sharprepository

Tags: dbcontext, sharp-repository, tracker-enabled-dbcontext

I have a custom dbcontext which name is Tracker-enabled DbContext (https://github.com/bilal-fazlani/tracker-enabled-dbcontext).I want to use it for audit log

And how can I implement EFRepository?

I implemented tracker-enabled-context but i cant solve how override sharp repo commit method.

```
public class HayEntities : TrackerContext
   {
    static HayEntities()
    {
      Database.SetInitializer<HayEntities>(null);
    }
    public HayEntities() : base(HayEntities)
    {
      this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
      this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
      this.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
    }
    public DbSet<Dummy> Dummys{ get; set; }  
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new DummyConfiguration());

    } }
  }
 public class DummyRepository : ConfigurationBasedRepository<DE.Dummy, long>, IDummyRepository
    {
        private readonly IRepository<DE.Dummy, long> _servisHasarRepository;
        public DummyRepository (HayEntities hayEntities,    ICachingStrategy<DE.Dummy, long> cachingStrategy = null)
        {this.CachingEnabled = false;
            _dummyRepository = new EfRepository<DE.Dummy, long>(hayEntities, cachingStrategy);
        }
public void UpdateOrCreate() {
 //In this area how can override save/commit method
}
  }
```

Comment: Hi. Can you show us what you have tried so far, so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to tell SharpRepository to use an IoC provider to inject the DbContext.  This will take care of getting the proper DbContext for your EfRepository.

If you want to control things based on the configuration and have custom repositories so you can implement your own mehods like UpdateOrCreate() then you would inherit from ConfigurationBasedRepository as you have in the example.

There are more details on setting up IoC with SharpRepository here: http://fairwaytech.com/2013/02/sharprepository-configuration/ (look in the "Entity Framework and Sharing the DbContext" section)

First look on NuGet for SharpRepository.Ioc.* to find the specific IoC you are using.  If you are using StructureMap then you would do something like this.

In your StructureMap configuration:

```
// Hybrid (once per thread or ASP.NET request if you’re in a web application)
For<DbContext>()
    .HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
    .Use<HayEntities>()
    .Ctor<string>("connectionString").Is(entityConnectionString);
```

Then you need to tell SharpRepository to use StructureMap by calling this in your startup code:

```
RepositoryDependencyResolver.SetDependencyResolver(new StructureMapDependencyResolver(ObjectFactory.Container));
```

After doing these things, then if you use EfRepository then it will know to ask StructureMap for the DbContext.

Now in your example above where you are using ConfigurationBasedRepository, I would suggest setting the caching in the configuration file instead of in code since you are using the configuration to load the repository.  Since IoC is handling the DbContext you don't need to do anyhing with that and you can focus on the custom method you want to write.

```
public class DummyRepository : ConfigurationBasedRepository<DE.Dummy, long>, IDummyRepository
{
    public void UpdateOrCreate()
    {
        // You have access to the underlying IRepository<> which is going to be an EfRepository in your case assuming you did that in the config file
        // here you can call Repository.Add(), or Reposiory.Find(), etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But do you have any sample SimpleInjector?

Comment: There is a SimpleInjector nuget package that you can use in a similar manner to StructureMap: http://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpRepository.Ioc.SimpleInjector/